How to perform cascade delete of child entities while deleting a parent entity?
When I perform a DELETE request to remove a record, the parent entity gets deleted as expected, but the child entity is not deleted.
I attempted to manually execute the process from the database source, but it still isn't working.

Needs more details on what is child entity

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
